# how to handle response get html format

Tags: android

> Error Log cat:retrofit.RetrofitError:
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

```
respons server:<div class="loader">
    <img class="loader" style="width: 32px; margin: 10px auto; display: block;" src="http://Home.com/img/bu_loading.gif">
    </div>
    <form id="SatisForm"  action="http://www.Home.com/SS/ecure/demo2.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="816764744736727737776722746733744827751737736738744795820820817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816784739736724747776722752733744733817712816792784739736724747776722752733744733817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816755733736727746776727743733770739817712816792755733736727746776727743733770739817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816771726727737727776727735736733817721816792771726727737727776727735736733817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816760733743737722754724733735736722737722817816792760733743737722754724733735736722737722817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816763722746733743736722746733724733770739746817816792763722746733743736722746733724733770739746817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816776727752722731722746778733741733817721816792776727752722731722746778733741733817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816782727723784739736724747817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816782727723779752727770739817721816792782727723779752727770739817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816764741817712719713814713714718814712714814713718816792764741817
```

2772472774373673373673373577872274373373173381782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782782781676774372772673376772274374675675678171381771371571281679276827827827816792782727723784739736724747817827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827827816792764744736727737776722746733744817712" name="satisXML"/>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit3dform').click();
        });

code :

```
void addSeatPaymnet(@Query("api.key")String key,
                        @Query("userid")String userid,
                        @Query("gender")String gender,
                        @Query("FirmaNo")String FirmaNo,
                        @Query("hatNo")String hatNo,
                        @Query("departure_city")String departure,
                        @Query("seatNo[]")String seatNo,
                        @Query("seferTakipNo")String seferTakipNo,
                        @Query("tarih")String tarih,
                        @Query("price")String price,
                        @Query("destination_city")String destination_city,
                        @Query("No_of_passenger")String No_of_passenger,
                        @Query("credit_card_holder_name")String credit_card_holder_name,
                        @Query("credit_card_number")String credit_card_number,
                        @Query("credit_card_security_code")String credit_card_security_code,
                        @Query("credit_card_expiry_month")String credit_card_expiry_month,
                        @Query("credit_card_expiry_year")String credit_card_expiry_year,
                        @Query("email")String email,
                        @Query("customer_name")String customer_name,
                        @Query("customer_surname")String customer_surname,
                        @Query("customer_mobile")String customer_mobile,
                        @Query("saat")String saat,
                        @Query("tc_number")String tc_number,
                        @Query("travelDate")String travelDate,
                        Callback<List<PaymentDetailBean> >callback);
```

---

```
RestClient.post().addSeatPaymnet(appConstants.api_key, "119", "2", "284", "284", "abc", "2", "687036", "2016-02-26", "75", "bcd",
                "1", "abdusl", "4222 3160 8933 0000", "242", "11", "2018", "patel@gmail.com",
                "abc", "raul", "312155555", "MTkwMC0wMS0wMV==", "1900-01-01T05:00:00-02:00", "07 March 2016 - 10:00", new Callback<List<PaymentDetailBean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(List<PaymentDetailBean> paymentDetailBeans, Response response) {
                        Log.d("success", "1"+response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.d("success", "2" + error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what is json you are getting from server ?

Comment: Also paste PaymentDetailBean class

Comment: Clearly Shows that problem in your model or bean class expect something and you getting soemthing else Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column

Comment: your server responds with HTML page and not a JSON, that's what i can see from your posted data.